# Symfony CSRF invalid token: Mismatch between token in URL and token in form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, token, csrf

I want to implement a form in Symfony that filters a data set for me.

The extract of my twig file as well as the the FilterType that is used for the form are shown below.

**list.html.twig**

```
{% block filterContent %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            {#This renders a red banner if the form contains errors.#}
            {#If the form variable is not called "form", pass it explicitly.#}
            {% include 'Form/form_errors_banner.html.twig' with {'form': form} %}
            {{ form_row(form.component) }}
            {{ form_row(form._token) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>

        <input type="reset" id="resetter" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs" value="{{ 'label.resetAll'|trans }}"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs" value="{{ 'label.applyFilter'|trans }}"/>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
    <!-- <br clear="all" /> -->
{% endblock filterContent %}
```

**FilterType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setAction($options['data']['url'])
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('component', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label'       => 'Component',
            'placeholder' => 'Select Component',
            'choices'     => array(
                'All'      => 'All',
                'Document' => 'Document',
                'User'     => 'User',
                'Waiver'   => 'Waiver'
            ),
            'required'    => false,
        ));
}
```

For some reason I get the following error message indicating that my CSRF token is invalid.
[CSRF invalid error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw31o.png)

After having a closer look into this, I suspect that the error is caused, because the CSRF token in the transmitted URL differs from the one that is sent with the form:
[CSRF token mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytWYQ.png)

I already tried to remove `{{ form_row(form._token) }}` line in my twig file and cleared my browser and server cache, but still the error message pops up.

Could anyone help me and tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In FilterType.php, ensure that you are using the same ID for your token as in your twig form. You can customize it via configureOptions:

```php
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_token_id' => FilterType::class
        ]);
    }
```